# How to make own interpreter in Java?

Tags: java, interpreter

I'm writing Java appication that sends messages on different sites (like spamer). Of course this should contains configs for each site. In different site different logic of send message and so on... I want write configs for sites like mini-programs, and interpret it in Java.

How to write interpreter of some pseudo-language in Java?
Or maybe there is some scripting language that interprets by Java very easy? (Python maybe?)

Comment: Did you consider embedding some scripting interpreter in your application?

Comment: I want to have text config file for each site. Which contains any simple instructions like: "click('//anyform/anybutton')". And Java application would read this file. And would execute some function which writen on Java. String by string...

Comment: google gives easily http://java-source.net/open-source/scripting-languages

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082795/custom-interpreter-in-java?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

You certainly won't need to write one from scratch... Some options:

- [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino) is a free, open source JavaScript interpreter built in Java.
- [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) interprets the Ruby language in Java.

This should suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Java Scripting API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/):

> The Java<sup>TM</sup> Scripting API is a scripting language indepedent framework for using script engines from Java code. With the Java Scripting API, it is possible to write customizable/extendable applications in the Java language and leave the customization scripting language choice to the end user. The Java application developer need not choose the extension language during development.

This way, you can integrate your application with many different scripting languages using a unified API.